# Vb.Net How to Access Unknown Controls Declared In Form, But Not Contained in Form.Controls

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way that I can programmically access/reference controls declared in a form (myForm.designer.vb) under these conditions:

A.) The name of the control is not always known, and

B.) The control has not been added to the collection myForm.Controls?

For Instance myForm.Designer.vb would contain the line

```
  Friend WithEvents [UnknownControlName] As [KnownControlType]
```

But does NOT contain the line

```
  Me.Controls.Add(Me.[UnknownControlName])
```

Ultimately, I am trying to step through ALL of the controls in the form (not just the ones in myForm.Controls), and if the control TYPE matches what I am looking for it gets added to a collection no matter what the name might be.  How do I do this?

Comment: One wonders why you have controls declared in your form designer, that aren't designed to be part of your form? One wonders very much.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - That would be a good thing to wonder, and this is why. I am working with a custom control (not made by myself) that has the bad habit of needing additional components added at design time (which are added to the parent form), but does not clean these up when getting deleted off the form.  I am trying to rectify this problem.  I either want these design-time created sub-controls to get removed from the form when the custom control does, OR I would like to be able to access them later so that I can quickly just add them to a new instance of the custom control.

Comment: is this the treeview thing?  The really bad thing is that those will accumulate until there are many of them.  Sounds like they arent actually added to the form (Me.Controls.Add) but declared in the designer but not added to the TV thing's colleciton.  IIRC its UIEditor is just a collection editor which adds the controls to the underlying collection for us.  What might be happening is that they are not properly tagged for serialization and are lost from the collection that way.  The best way to remove them would be to fix the underlying problem (I know, magic wand time).

Comment: @Plutonix - Mostly right, but... the columns ARE getting into the TreeView column collection.  Ok, so I think we are on to something though.  How does the collection editor add and delete controls to and from the form?  What method of what class is called to do that.  I can simply recreate that code in the control whenever it gets deleted at design time. You suggested before that I should slip that code into the dispose method of the control.  That didn't seem to work.  Are you sure that is the right place?

Comment: If they are in the TV controls collection they are not orphans.  They would never be added to Me.Controls anymore than a TabPage would (they are all added to TabControl.Controls).  They would still need to be declared in the designer though. So, if they are in the TV collection, they cant also be part of the form collection, so I am confused what you are wanting to clean up.  They DO have to be declared in the designer (like a TabPg or LV Col) in order to be added to the TV, but those arent orphans.

Comment: @Plutonix - Ok, this may take a couple posts... When creating a new Treecolumn(TC) through the collection editor in the TV properties, the column get DECLARED in the form containing the TV (Friend WithEvents TC1...), but does NOT get added to the form's "controls" (Me.Controls.Add(meTC1)).  It DOES get added to the TreeView (Me.TVA1.Columns.Add(Me.TC1)).  I can at that point programmically access that column through (TVA.Columns).  If I delete the TV at design time, the line that added the column to the TV (along with all the other auto-generated TV lines get removed from myForm.Designer.vb).

Comment: The problem is that the line declaring the TreeColumn (Friend WithEvents TC1 as treeColumn) does not get deleted from the designer.  To a person just starting off with this control, this would cause very confusing behaviors.  Namely, if they add another TV to the form (after deleting the 1st one), and try to add a column with the same name to the TV they will get an error that a column with that name already exists, and yet they have no idea where it resides or why it still exists.  This is what I am trying to fix.  When a TV is delete, the declaring statement for the column aslo gets deleted.

Comment: Something you made me realize, however, is that the collection editor UI has a button each for adding and removing these TCs.  When pressing those buttons the DECLARING statements are created or deleted in the designer file for the form.  If I can find what code runs behind those buttons, I can delete these declaring statements automatically at the deleting of the TV from the form by putting them in the Dispose method.

Comment: Ok, the crux is the child declares are not deleted when a TV is **deleted**.  That was not mentioned. Add/Remove does not add/remove from the designer.  It just acts on the underlying collection.  It now sounds like a serialization problem - or maybe disposal.  If you just remove a Col from a TV does it linger in the designer?   You could manually dispose cols in Finalize, and/or maybe OnControlRemoved.  Or it could just be one of the serializer requirements.  Hard to tell without code.

Comment: @Plutonix - F'n A!  I figured it out... I think.  I have some debug testing to make sure I'm not causing more problems, but when I have confirmed, I will put the answer up.  Thanks Plutonix, while you didn't give me the exact answer, talking it though helped alot.  To answer your question, if you remove the TC from the TV it does NOT linger in the designer.  That was the key, I just used the same code the collection editor did.  Namely, DestroyInstance.

Comment: Control/Components get added to the designer when you click OK (just tested).  What is probably wrong is one of the serialize attributes or ShouldSerializeXXXX or ResetXXXXX methods.  The form would not know when/how to remove controls if those are wonky.  Again, hard to tell without code.

Comment: @Plutonix - Outside of MSDN, can you suggest any resources that are good at explaining the ins and outs of serialization of objects.  When to use it, why, and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

A Collection property would be implemented something like this:

```
' backing field, actual collection
Private _TargetControls As New Collection(Of Control)

<EditorAttribute(GetType(DlgFormControlCollectionUIEditor), _
    GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))> _
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)> _
Public Property TargetControls() As Collection(Of Control)
    Get
        Return _TargetControls
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Collection(Of Control))
        _TargetControls = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The EditorAttribute tells VS the class which will be used to Edit the property at design time.  In this case, it is a custom editor class named `DlgFormControlCollectionUIEditor`.  To use the built in .NET Collection Editor it would be more like this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design
...
<Editor(GetType(CollectionEditor), GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))>
```

VS will use the basic editor, to provide a Dialog to edit the Public properties (not fields or members) of the underlying class.  That is, if the property is a `Collection(Of Foo)` the editor will list the public members of `Foo` for the user to edit.

When you click Ok/Done in whatever UITypeEditor, VS adds the Type to the project.  If `Foo` is a class object, they get added to the `Collection(Of Foo)`.  If 'Foo' is a Component or Control, the proper `Friend Foo1 As Foo...` statements are also added to the form designer.

The `DesignerSerializationVisibility` attribute tells VS how to treat the Property.  Typically, we want VS to save all the info about a control, such as a TextBox.  With a collection, instead you want to save the CONTENTS of the collection.

In addition, you need to tell VS how to tell when the contents of the Collection has changed (I dont recall seeing this part when I was looking at that prj, but that just means weeks later I dont recall having seen it).  These are the `ShouldSerialize` function and `Reset` method:

```
Public Sub ResetTargetControls()
    _TargetControls = Nothing
    ' or other logic: like '_TargetControls.Clear'
End Sub

Public Function ShouldSerializeTargetControls() As Boolean
    Return _TargetControls IsNot Nothing
    ' or 'Return True' since backing field is instanced
    ' or 'Return _TargetControls.Count > 0'   maybe
End Function
```

I have gotten serialization MsgBox errors after returning from the editor when there is something wrong with these - VS just doesnt know if it should serialize the data.  If you tinkered with the property names, these might be broke, as the property name is integrated into the procedure names (this goes with the `TargetControls` property above).  VS uses these to determine if the Collection (contents in this case) has changed.  If those are wonky VS might not know to remove children from the collection when the parent control is removed from the form.

That should be all you need to do, but you could also look at good working examples of custom TabControls to see how they go about no leaving TabPage orphans declared on the form.  There is also the chance that there is something about the Column object which requires special handling (or more likely a bug) when destroyed.  This [CP article about Collection Editors](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372/How-to-Edit-and-Persist-Collections-with-Collectio) is good but a little skimpy on the 'persist' part which is serialization.

HTH